# Why did Gandalf put the dwarves and the hobbit in danger of going through the cursed forest?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Why did Gandalf put the dwarves and the hobbit in danger in *The Desolation of Smaug* by going through the "cursed forest"?

Gandalf clearly said he would go another way around, which means there's another way around other than going through the cursed forest. So why didn't they just follow Gandalf the other way around instead of going through the "cursed forest"?

Comment: Because they had little fat ponies and he has the fastest horse in the entire universe?

Comment: @Valorum I'm not sure whether you are referencing Gwaihir here, but IIRC Gandalf only gets the fastest ***horse*** when enters Rohan in *LotR*

Comment: @NikitaNeganov - Actually that's a fair point, but he's still the only one with an actual horse.

Comment: Don't have quotes with me at the moment, but (as far as I remember) Gandalf wasn't going round the forest, he was on his way to Dol Guldor to face the Necromancer (i.e. Sauron).

Comment: Sure, the cursed forest was the most dangerous thing, and the dragon at the destination wouldn't harm a fly... They were working under a time restraint, so chose the shortest path.

Comment: He needed to level up the party a bit more before the Boss Fight.

Comment: Part of it would also be that at the time of writing the Necromancer was only there to give a reason for Gandalf to leave the group. Remember it wasn't meant to have a  sequel and only by chance did a publisher see it and like it enough to want to publish it.

Comment: They could have just rung up the eagles and hitched a ride. Would have made for a shorter story tho.

Comment: Don't forget Gandalf is a Maiar.  This means he was present at the creation of the universe during the Music of the Ainur.  If you haven't read The Silmarillion, that means that he was present when everything fated to occur was sung into being.  None of the Maiar remember it all, but they all do remember bits and pieces.  This means they occasionally have foreknowledge of things.  Maybe Gandalf simply knew they'd be ok.

Comment: I haven't read the book in years but don't remember Mirkwood being called the cursed forest. Is this name a film thing?

Answer (score 74):

## Because that was the shortest and least dangerous route to go

Just to clarify: Gandalf wasn't going by another path to Erebor by himself, he was heading to Dol Guldur first with The White Council , then *afterwards* rejoining Bilbo and the Dwarves.  The other way round that Gandalf mentions would take the party more time to travel, in addition to being more dangerous. Bilbo himself asks Gandalf this.

> "Do we really have to go through?" groaned the hobbit.
>
> "Yes, you do!" said the wizard, "if you want to get to the other side. You must either go through or give up your quest. And I am not going to allow you to back out now, Mr. Baggins. I am ashamed of you for thinking of it. You have got to look after all these dwarves for me," he laughed. "No! no!" said Bilbo. "I didn't mean that. **I meant, is there no way round?"**
>
> **"There is, if you care to go two hundred miles or so out of your way north, and twice that south. But you wouldn't get a safe path even then. There are no safe paths in this part of the world.** Remember you are over the Edge of the Wild now, and in for all sorts of fun wherever you go. Before you could get round Mirkwood in the North you would be right among the slopes of the Grey Mountains, and they are simply stiff with goblins, hobgoblins, and orcs of the worst description. Before you could get round it in the South, you would get into the land of the Necromancer; and even you. Bilbo, won't need me to tell you tales of that black sorcerer. I don't advise you to go anywhere near the places overlooked by his dark tower! Stick to the forest-track, keep your spirits up, hope for the best, and with a tremendous slice of luck you may come out one day and see the Long Marshes lying below you, and beyond them, high in the East, the Lonely Mountain where dear old Smaug lives, though I hope he is not expecting you."
>
> <sub>*The Hobbit*, Queer Lodgings</sub>

Cutting straight through Mirkwood on the [Old Forest Road](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Old_Forest_Road) would take far less time. That does not mean it wasn't dangerous, as Beorn himself notes that goblins used that road.

> But Beorn had warned them that that way was now often used by the goblins, while the forest-road itself, he had heard, was overgrown and disused at the eastern end and led to impassable marshes where the paths had long been lost.
>
> <sub>*The Hobbit*, Queer Lodgings</sub>

You can see for yourself on this map: To go North? An extra 200 miles and guaranteed goblins at the end? No thank you. 400 extra miles South and going near Dol Guldur? I'll pass. Going through Mirkwood on the Old Forest Road; goblins, possibly, but it would sure take a ton of time off the journey.

So their last alternative, [the Elf-path and also their route of choice](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Elf-path), seemed the most ideal because, like the Old Forest Road, it was a shortcut through Mirkwood to Erebor. However unlike the latter it was a lesser-known path, meaning the chances of meeting goblins were much less on that path than any other. (Thanks @chepner)

> North of the Carrock the edge of Mirkwood drew closer to the borders of the Great River, and though here the Mountains too drew down nearer, Beorn advised them to take this way; for at a place a few days' ride due north of the Carrock was the gate of a little-known pathway through Mirkwood that led almost straight towards the Lonely Mountain.
>
> <sub>*The Hobbit*, Queer Lodgings</sub>

#### Map of Wilderland

[image: Mirkwood map]

> The map of Wilderland drawn by Christopher Tolkien and included in most editions of The Hobbit.

As you can see on the above map the Elf-Path is located a little more North as compared to the Old Forest Road, and would clearly take the party far less time travelling on it and through the forest, than going either North or South to avoid Mirkwood.

Comment: Note that they didn't take the Old Forest Road, but another path known by Beorn that was further to the North (and not on this map). Said road was closer to Beorn's, less likely to be used by goblins, and exits the forest closer to Erebor. (See https://wordsathome2.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/hobbit-map-wilderland1.jpg, looking for the elf path marked in a dotted line halfway between the northern end of the forest and the Old Forest Road.)

Comment: (Sorry, ignore the statement that the elf path was closer to Beorn's.)

Comment: I think their original plan, though, was indeed to take the Old Forest Road (lining up as it does with the High Pass), so the same conversation probably would have resulted :)

Comment: Just as an aside: when The Hobbit was first written (and published first in 1937) i.e. before it was thought it'd have a sequel let alone published the Necromancer was only there to give a reason for Gandalf to leave the group for a while. Oh and might as well say it too talking about the earlier times. Originally Gandalf was the name of one of the Dwarves (take a guess which one). And.. the original name of Smaug is what I called myself here - Pryftan.

Comment: @Pryftan Do you have a source for that?  I recall hearing that *Lord of the Rings* came first--in broad strokes if not in its finished form--and Tolkein came up with *The Hobbit* as a prequel to set up its backstory.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Which part? But yes. If you look at the first edition of The Hobbit Gollum was apologising very much that he couldn't give the Ring up (it was just a literary device at that time) because Bilbo already had it. And for the part about Gandalf needing a reason to leave? It's in the Letters. As for the other parts it's in The History of The Hobbit. Did I miss anything else? By all means let me know.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Also he had already written much about the First Age. No. The reason he wrote The L.R. (as he sometimes abbreviated it) is it was requested that he write a sequel. And he had some difficulty with it too. He had no problem writing many versions of the first chapter (iirc there are four in The Return of the Shadow which is vol VI of HoMe and the first part of the history of The L.R.) but later on there were issues and times where he stopped for a good while (part of that being duties).

Comment: It's also mentioned that it's a good thing they _didn't_ follow the Old Forest Road, as that got lost in swampy land at the eastern end and it would have delayed them no end, and then they would have had to trek north to Laketown through empty lands.

Comment: @Pryftan: Fun fact, the reason why Gandalf was initially one of the dwarves is that Tolkien stole the whole thing including the names from various sources. Dwarf names happen to be the names of dwarves in Snorri Sturluson's stories. All of them, Gandalf included.

Comment: @Damon I have The History of The Hobbit; every volume of HoMe, Unfinished Tales and many more books - so .. yes I know about the names. Even so I wouldn't say they're 'stolen' as such but certainly there are inspirations. Incidentally The Peoples of Middle Earth has a lot of fascinating things on names including of the Hobbits (surnames and forenames). In the chapter The Appendix on Languages (Appendix? I think so but I"m vague atm).

Comment: @Damon I just reread your comment. In fact the source of my information is the The History of The Hobbit which indeed has the names as well as points out that Gandalf was first a dwarf. But thanks for the information - you couldn't have known that I knew that. Oh and re 'inspirations': that's arguably a very wrong word but I couldn't think of anything better to use so I used 'inspiration'. Anyway thank you!

Comment: "... simply stiff with goblins..." Gandalf really leans into the Westron speech patterns for this story.

Answer (score 8):

Because unless they were terminally stupid and left the path, they were relatively safe.  All they had to do was to keep following a wide path, going in a straight line, as instructed by an uber-powerful wizard who knew everything about the world and an uber-powerful werebear who knew everything about that area of the world.  You'd have to be some kind of idiot to wander off the path, hoping that the wood elves (the natural enemies of dwarfs) would welcome you to their fireside and feed you.

Oh wait...

Comment: I prefer to think that the Hobbit was a short story written by Tolkien for children and it was the quickest path to more interesting parts of the story.

Comment: This answer overstates its case, seems to indicate at the end that it is wrong and does not seem to be based on any specific evidence.

Comment: @PJTraill Overstates how? They had no problems following the path, and there were no dangers on the path apart from the stream which put them to sleep. I'm hardly exaggerating the powers and knowledge of Gandalf or Beorn. And in Tolkien, dwarfs and elves do not get along.

Comment: *seems to suggest at the end that is wrong*... Allow me to introduce you to the concept of irony. Like "You'd have to be some kind of idiot to misunderstand that. Oh wait..." All clear now? ;)

Comment: Maybe I understand: _Oh wait_ ⇒ they actually _were_ idiots … that is why Gandalf put them in danger (what the questioner asked) … I fear I still do not see why you undercut your answer, rather than saying _the alternatives were worse_. Overstated in that the powers of Gandalf and Beorn _are_ limited, Beorn says the way is “dark, dangerous and difficult”, they did have to cope with the stream & the deer that knocked Bombur in, they were running out of food & drink & the elf-road “now came to a doubtful … end” (among bogs) “at the … edge of the forest; only the river offered … a safe way”.

Comment: As you say, they actually *were* idiots.  Gandalf didn't put them in danger, they got *themselves* into danger, after Gandalf and Beorn sent them on a relatively safe route.  Sure, it's a children's book, but Tolkien seems to go out of his way to make the dwarfs (who allegedly are all adults) behave childishly, in comparison to contemporary books featuring children (think Enid Blyton) where the children behave more like adults.

Comment: While I do not agree with your view on the question/answer, I find your comments on children _v._ adults intriguing – must give that some thought!

Answer (score 1):

> "Do we really have to go through?" groaned the hobbit.
>
> "Yes, you do!" said the wizard, "if you want to get to the other side."

Gandalf isn't just talking about the other side of the forest he's also talking about the journey. Without Bilbo going through Mirkwood he wouldn't have had the courage to talk to Smaug.